# Load skin CSS internally instead of a link in HTML head on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to load the skin CSS in the head of the page in `<style></style>` tags instead of linking to it as `<link href="/wp-content/thesis/skins/nina-cross-promo/css.css" rel="stylesheet" />`, but so far without much luck.

Can you please recommend a function for my custom_functions.php so that I can grab the contents of that CSS file, minify it with:

```
function minimizeCSSsimple($css){
$css = preg_replace('/\/\*((?!\*\/).)*\*\//','',$css); // negative look ahead
$css = preg_replace('/\s{2,}/',' ',$css);
$css = preg_replace('/\s*([:;{}])\s*/','$1',$css);
$css = preg_replace('/;}/','}',$css);
return $css;
}
```

and then insert in the `head` as `<style>My minified css</style>` so it will look like this:

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<style>My minified CSS</style>
```

and not like this:

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<link href="/wp-content/thesis/skins/nina-cross-promo/css.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Please help

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve by this?

Comment: Two things, first to be able to minify my skin CSS and then eliminate render-blocking CSS in my HTML without making a change to the skin itself

Answer (score 0):

You can add your minified css within site head tag by as follows -

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_custom_styles' );
function add_custom_styles(){
    ?>
    <style type="text/css">
        <?php 
        $custom_css = "Your custom css goes here";
        echo $custom_css; 
        ?>
    </style>
    <?php
}
```

Add this codes in your active theme's functions.php

Comment: Thanks, but this is not going to remove the initial stylesheet that is already loaded.

Comment: @AlexB, you have to dequeue skins style first. To dequeue your style see the [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_style)

Comment: it is impossible to do as style does not have an ID to grab it by with dequeue

Comment: Can you tell me the way of skin's css actually added.

Comment: That's a trouble I am having. I am trying to figure it out. The theme is Thesis and the skin that I use in Thesis is Nina Cross Promo, which has a stylesheet that is loaded in the head, but I cannot figure out how as Thesis has a skin editor and this CSS can be altered from within that editor